# determining complex torch.dtype with precision/range equivalent to a given type

Tags: pytorch

I want to create functions that support different precision, the floating point precision is the data type for the real and imaginary parts.

Basically I would like to use a native method to translate between the real and complex types like

```
float16 <-> complex32
float32 <-> complex64
float64 <-> complex128
```

If I want to use a hardcoded type we can do, for instance

```py
torch.float32 # 45ns
```

I know that if I have a complex type I can get at least the string form of the the real counterpart. Then we could get the real counterpart as

```py
getattr(torch, torch.finfo(torch.complex64).dtype) # ~400ns
```

I know I can get the complex counterpart by constructing a minimum tensor and viewing it as complex

```py
torch.view_as_complex(torch.zeros(2, dtype=torch.float16)).dtype # ~3200ns
```

Or even a zero element tensor

```py
torch.view_as_complex(torch.zeros(0,2, dtype=torch.float16)).dtype # ~3900ns
```

But this code is too ugly to be repeatedly typed

```py
def complex_type(dtype):
    '''
    Returns the type for a complex number with the same precision 
    as the given dtype
    '''
    if(dtype.is_complex):
        return dtype;
    else:
        return torch.view_as_complex(torch.zeros([], dtype=dtype)).dtype
```

Comment: To be honest, as there is only a handful number of float->complex pairs, I'd put them in a dictonary and map from one type to the other.

Comment: I would also just use a dictionary, but if you really want to use something packaged with pytorch, in torch.onnx.symbolic_helper there's an array called `scalar_type_to_pytorch_type` you could use.  Something like `scalar_type_to_pytorch_type[scalar_type_to_pytorch_type.index(torch.complex32)+int(math.log(torch.finfo(WHATEVER).resolution)/-12)]` would convert to the appropriately sized complex type.